# Q&A plugin for Confluence

Tags: jira, confluence

I would like to have Q&A module in Confluence, where one employee would raise a question about the problem he has, and another one would respond. I'd like to have rating there, where everybody can up- and down-vote questions and answers. I'd like it to be almost the same as stackoverflow.com.

Is there any plugins available at Atlassian Marketplace? I tried to google it, but I had no luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, when Atlassian wanted such an application they chose to use [OSQA](http://www.osqa.net/) instead of Confluence. That's what powers [Atlassian Answers](http://answers.atlassian.com).

Comment: It seems that Atlassian decided to implement their own Q&A plugin for Confluence, so they can charge up to $9000 for it. Still, the funny part is that they own Q&A website is still using OSQA. It's like having a Microsoft salesmen running Ubuntu on his company laptop :)

Comment: Link to the Confluence Q&A plugin: https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence-questions